# How can weight lifting and running be done concurrently?

Tags: running, weightlifting

I have been running for about 2 years and could do a 25 minute 5k. I recently started doing squats, 5x95, 5x105 so on and up to 5x125. I used to be able to Squat about 190. My runs are much slower after starting weight lifting. I believe that my legs aren't recovering enough between days, but I have reduced squats to twice per week and am still slowing down.

My goal is to increase my ability to power up hills without compromising my endurance. How should I be approaching this?

Comment: pounds or kilograms?

Comment: pounds.  I'm working up to kg :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Treat squats like a sprint workout. Take 1-2 easy days afterwards on your legs. This means any runs should be only 30 minutes at an easy pace. Even if your not too sore the next day take that day easy by running no more than 1 hour at an easy pace.

Comment: Yeah, that's more or less what I ended up having to do, and it's working a bit better now.  I'm noticing a stronger ability to run up hills but my times are still suffering a little bit.  However, I think that it's just tweaking now

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky I didnt even notice your goal and additional question at the end. I think sprints might be better than squats but I prefer staying out of the gym. Treadmills at 12-14% inclines or actual tempo runs up hills would be best but I think you probably know this.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to be good at running, then squats will not help. Include a hill in your daily runs, and some sprints. But if you are after overall fitness keep mixing weights and endurance. You will be stronger, and you will have more overall endurance for a variety of activities.

Comment: So I am indeed after general fitness, but id like to know how to avoid losing running efficiency while also lifting weight